# PHP if not equal(!=) and or (||) issue

Tags: php

i have this code :

```
if (($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}' || ($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse')
```

but not work and also i do

```
if(!in_array($value->TEXT,array('PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}','PrÃ©presse')))
```

but not worked i have in the `$value` text contains the statement and i don't want display this string `PrÃ©presse`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. Though you should use `AND` in your first if condition.

Comment: `if (($value->TEXT) !=='PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}'  && ($value->TEXT) !=='PrÃ©presse')`

Comment: Yes, in the first condition it's always going to be true as it's impossible for the string to NOT be either of those.

Answer (score 5):

This statement is always going to return `true`:

```
if (($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}' || ($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse')
```

because:

- if `($value->TEXT) =='PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}'` then  `($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse')`
- if `($value->TEXT) =='PrÃ©presse')` then `($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}'`

---

Change the line to:

```
if (($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}' && ($value->TEXT) !='PrÃ©presse')
```

---

This is explored in the Wikipedia article on [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which states:

> The rules allow the expression of conjunctions and disjunctions purely in terms of each other via negation.
>
> The rules can be expressed in English as:
>
> The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.
> The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations.
>
> or informally as:
>
> **"not (A and B)"** is the same as **"(not A) or (not B)"**
> also,
> **"not (A or B)"** is the same as **"(not A) and (not B)"**.

Comment: You mean the statement is always going to return true.

Answer (score 0):

The first code should use `&&` instead of `||` to simulate same result as the second code.

Also, the parentheses around `$value->TEXT` are unnecessary.

```
if($value->TEXT != 'PrÃ©presse{/CR}{/CR}' && $value->TEXT !='PrÃ©presse')
```

If they don't work for you, try doing a `var_dump` on `$value->TEXT` to see if it is different from the strings you are trying to match.

Comment: it's not worked for me i don't know whay?? and i var_dumped the $value->TEXT i have the array'size=1 string 'PrÃ©presse Achat..;

Comment: So your $value->TEXT isn't same as the ones you are checking against, right? They only contain it, but not equal, right?

Comment: the $value->TEXT contains  PrÃ©presse i need display the $value->TEXT whitout display PrÃ©presse for that i do this conditions but not worked

Comment: Use `strpos`. `if(strpos($value->TEXT, 'PrÃ©presse') !== false)`